# toggle form between display between specific input fields and full form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in a page that means to manage jobs posted in another page.  The form has a few key fields that decide if the job posting gets approved or rejected. I would like the form to display initially only those fields specified as critical or key to the selection process.  And also have a toggle button to display the full form in case the reviewer want more info on the particular job being reviewed.

How do I specify the fields I want to make critical?

And how do I toggle between those fields and the full form?

The form I have so far is this (critical inputs are Industry, Experience and Skills required):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
    <div class="w-section inverse">
        <div class="w-box sign-in-wr bg-5">
            <div class="form-body">
                <h5>
                    Please provide the following information about employment opportunity.
                </h5>
                <div class="row">
                    <form class="form-light padding-20" id="addJob">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <label style="font-size:16px;" data-for="title">Title</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <label style="font-size:16px;" data-for="salary">Salary</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="salary" id="salary" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <label style="font-size:16px;" data-for="location">Location</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="location" id="location" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <label style="font-size:16px;" data-for="company">Company</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <label style="font-size:16px;" data-for="jobDescription">Job Description</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jobdescription" id="jobdescription" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label style="font-size:16px;" data-for="industry">Industry</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="industry" id="industry" placeholder="">
                                <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="profit" id="profit">Profit</a></label>
                                <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="nonprofit" id="nonprofit">Non-Profit</a></label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label style="font-size:16px;" data-for="experience">Experience</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="experience" id="experience" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <label style="font-size:16px;" data-for="reqSkills">Skills required</label>
                                <select name="requiredSkillsDropdown">
                                    <option value="HTML5">HTML5</option>
                                    <option value="CS3">CS3</option>
                                    <option value="javascrip">Javascript</option>
                                    <option value="jquery">jQuery</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <label style="font-size:16px;" data-for="workexp">Address</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="street" id="street" placeholder="Street">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" id="state" placeholder="State">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <label style="font-size:16px;" data-for="contact">Contact</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" id="zip" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-two pull-right" id="capturejobinfo" type="button">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This question is off-topic because it does not include any previous attempt at a solution. It lays out markup and requests a solution from readers. StackOverflow is geared at assisting with programming issues, not crowdsourcing your development projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the containers for the inputs a custom `data-*` attribute indicating if they are critical or not (sample from above)

```
<div class="col-lg-2" data-critical="true">
    <label style="font-size:16px;" data-for="experience">Experience</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="experience" id="experience" placeholder="">
</div>
```

And for others use `false` for `data-critical`. You can then toggle with:

```
$("div.form-group div[data-critical=true]").show(); //to show
```

Or `.hide()` to hide.